# Remove users from group with javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, jsom, groups

I found a script to add a user to a SP group with a button.
Now I would like to have a second button that does the opposite (remove the user from the group).

The first thing (adding an user) works. The second doesn't work. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
<script language="ecmascript" type="text/ecmascript">
var user;
var membersGroup;
function addUser2Members() {
     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
     var groupCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
     // Get the members group, assuming its ID is 22.
     membersGroup = groupCollection.getById(22);
     user = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
     var userCollection = membersGroup.get_users();
     userCollection.addUser(user);
     clientContext.load(user);
     clientContext.load(membersGroup);
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert(' Congratulations!' + '\n \n ' + user.get_title() + ' \n \n' + ' Has successfully joined the SharePoint Group:' + '\n \n ' + membersGroup.get_title());
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
function callAddUser() {
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(addUser2Members, "sp.js");
}

function removeUserFromGroup() {
     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
     var groupCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
     // Get the members group, assuming its ID is 22.
     membersGroup = groupCollection.getById(22);
     user = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
     var userCollection = membersGroup.get_users();
     userCollection.RemoveUser(user);
     clientContext.load(user);
     clientContext.load(membersGroup);
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded2), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed2));
}
function onQuerySucceeded2() {
    alert(' Congratulations!' + '\n \n ' + user.get_title() + ' \n \n' + ' Has successfully been deleted from the group:' + '\n \n ' + membersGroup.get_title());
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
}
function onQueryFailed2(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
function callRemoveUser() {
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(removeUserFromGroup, "sp.js");
}

</script>
<input onclick="javascript:callAddUser();" type="button" value="Join Now!"/>
<input onclick="javascript:callremoveUser();" type="button" value="unsubscribe"/>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error while calling `removeUserFromGroup` function??

Comment: Nothing is happening. I don't get an failed alert neither

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. Your function is called "callRemoveUser()" while your button onclick is called "callremoveUser()". The R must be uppercase in your input onclick event.

Comment: I changed that point, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Use F12 and see what/if you get any errors. And use breakpoints to debug!

Comment: I get the message: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'removeUser'  (I changed the R to r from removeUser)

Comment: I removed the second 'user' from userCollection.removeUser  And now it works!  Thanks for the help!